# how to delete a Triggered Send in Exact Target

Tags: marketing-cloud

i did find any option to delete a triggered send please let us know if we can delete it.
I need to delete a "Triggered Send" in Exact Target under my interactions tab

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually you can:
1. create a folder
2. move the triggered sends into the folder
3. delete the folder

Comment: I tried to rename the trigger in Salesforce but it created me another trigger send in the Exacttarget folder "trigger sends". I can't delete the email used in this "old" trigger send too...
Did someone found a solution? Thank you

Comment: The accepted answer is a work around that lets you delete it. Just make sure that all programs, etc that are linked to it are archived or removed correctly or it can cause issues.

Comment: WARNING! I just did this and it has caused me huge issues. When you delete the folder the triggers will be 'gone' and nowhere to be found, but, if you try to create a new trigger with the same info it will give you a warning saying the trigger already exists. You will end up with an inaccessible trigger that you can never modify. BE WARNED!

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you could not delete triggered sends through ExactTarget UI. Instead, you could archive them and move to a different folder.

Comment: Thanks Vijay. I did archive all these sends. but was looking to delete too. Now that i know it can not be deleted we decide to move in trash folder

Answer (score 0):

You can have a triggered send deleted instead of just archived. It requires opening a ticket with ET support & it could take a few days.

As Vjay stated, just archiving it & moving it to another folder is usually sufficient.

Another good option that you can do is to rename & update that trigger to point to a new email if needed.