# Create a folder for Triggered Sends

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

As per [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/67141/71795) answer, to delete a Triggered Send I can move it to a new folder and delete the folder. However, I can't  figure out how to create a folder. When I try to move a TS a folder explorer comes up only with the folder "Triggered Sends". The only option labelled "Create" is to create a new TS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct way to delete a Triggered Send:

1. Go to Interactions > Triggered Emails
2. From the dropdown menu on the left choose Messages > Triggered Sends
3. Right-click on the Triggered Sends tree node and click on Create new folder
   [image]
4. Create the new folder and name it whatever you like
5. Go back to the Triggered Sends folder and move your Triggered Send to the new folder
6. Right-click on the new folder and Delete it.

Comment: Thanks. I had right-clicked the "Triggered Sends" node but the context menu took so long to load that I thought there were no right-click options.

Comment: Just be warned the triggered sends are not actually deleted following this process.  They are 'deleted' from the UI, but are still somewhere out there and available thru Marketing Cloud Apis.This has the potential for issues and unwanted sends if you have some process somewhere still triggering them.

Comment: @Mike Yes. Someone at the linked answer commented about that and so I took precautions to avoid the "phantom" TS to be triggered unintentionally (paused the TS and updated its name and external key).